# Restore h2 database

Tags: java, database, swing, h2

I have used the h2 database for a Desktop based application (using swing). I also backed it up and stored it in my file system with the ".h2.db" extension.  This is not a readable file.  So how can I restore my h2 backup file?

Comment: Edits for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to create a ZIP file using a specific tool. It should be possible to use the tool on the copied file as well:

> The recommended way to backup a database is to create a compressed SQL
>   script file. This will result in a small, human readable, and database
>   version independent backup. Creating the script will also verify the
>   checksums of the database file. The Script tool is ran as follows:
>   java org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:~/test -user sa -script test.zip -options compression zip

The ZIP file can then be used to restore the DB:

> To restore a database from a SQL script file, you can use the
>   RunScript tool:
>   java org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/test -user sa -script 
>   test.zip -options compression zip

http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore