# Restore H2 database while having only a '.db' extension file

Tags: java, h2, restore

It is necessary to restore the h2 database. I have a file to recover, but its extension is .db, not .zip. I run h2 through the `java -jar ./h2-1.4.190.jar -browser` command. In the JDBC URL I indicate: **jdbc:h2:file:/opt/backup/my.h2.db** . I specify the password and login. The connection is made, I get to the database, but I don’t see my scheme. What should I do?

Comment: Could you please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868946/restore-h2-database  because , i think it's a duplicate question

Comment: @YoussefTounoussi,  This is not a duplicate, because no solution was found in that question. I have a file with the db extension, I do not have a file with the zip extension, as suggested in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include a file name extension into JDBC URL. The valid URL for such file is `jdbc:h2:/opt/backup/my;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE`.

Please note that 1.4.190 is a very old version, use it only if the database was really created with that version. (For the latest version of H2 exclude `MVCC` setting from the URL, it was removed from H2.)

Use a copy of your file. If it can't be opened normally, use a Recover Tool.
https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#using_recover_tool

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I tried to do so: jdbc:h2:file:/opt/backup/my.h2.db, but it was necessary so jdbc:h2:file:/opt/backup/my . Thanks to your help, everything worked!